# Zoho Creator - Retrieving the actual text value of a Form's Lookup Dropdown field

Tags: field, lookup, zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm following the Zoholics videos on Deluge and used this statement to lookup the pizza price from the Inventory:

```
colPizzaDetails = Inventory[Pizza == input.Pizza && Size == input.Pizza_Size];
```

This error is displayed when trying to save the script:

```
In Criteria left expression is of type STRING and right expression is of type BIGINT and the operator == is not valid
```

In the video, the narrator was able to save the script. Looks like a BIGINT is stored in the Lookup Dropdown now instead of text as shown in the video.

Can you tell me how to alter the code statement so I can change input.Pizza to represent the actual Pizza Name text that the user sees on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

It seams Inventory form is having the Pizza field as a string field.

And in the current form it seams Pizza field is a lookup from Pizza Form.

so whenever you try to access a lookup field , u'll get the Record ID in return, you can check it by logging that using alert or info command , example alert or info (input.Pizza) in u'r current form.

so first u'll need to fetch the pizza name from Pizza Form and then compare it in u'r query.

lets say pizza name field in Pizza Form is Pizza_Name;

so this is how u'r code should look

```
// fetch pizza_name : make sure you replace Pizza_Name 
// by the deluge name of pizza name field in pizza form.
pizza_name = Pizza[ID==input.Pizza].Pizza_Name; 

// compare pizza_name with inventory pizza and 
// fetch inventory data.
colPizzaDetails = Inventory[Pizza == pizza_name && Size == input.Pizza_Size];
```

and this should work fine.

OR

you can also try

```
colPizzaDetails = Inventory[Pizza == input.Pizza.Pizza_Name && Size == input.Pizza_Size];
```

but that can give you this error in some cases.

> Pizza is a lookup field and child fields cannot be accessed

so the First approach will work in all cases & is preferred approach from zoho standard point of view.

Answer (score 0):

you should convert the input result to an integer using toNumber() function Like this:

> colPizzaDetails = Inventory[Pizza == input.Pizza && Size ==
>   input.Pizza_Size.toNumber()];